# Functional way to get previous element during map

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, purely-functional

I have an array which I `map` over. I need to compare the current element with the previous. I am detecting if the current element is the same as the previous element by comparing their `id`s and doing something different based on this condition. Is there any purely functional way to do it without doing index math?

```
items.map((item, index) => {
    if(item.id === items[index - 1 > 0 ? index - 1 : 0].id) {
    // do something
} else {
   // do something else
 }
})
```

The code works but I would like to avoid doing math on the index. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Luckily, you are not mutating (or reassigning) the index here, you just have a conditional expression.

Comment: this isn't mutating index at all

Comment: Try `items.reduce((old, new) => {console.log(old === new); return (new)});` But you'll need to manually "map" values to another array (to match Array.map() behaviour)

Comment: You can write function like map that will iterate over item and give access to prev item. And then use this function instead of map. I think it's fine to have utilities functions non functional inside, if they are functional style outside.

Comment: Mutations require assignments, explicit ones (e.g. `index = ...`) or implicit ones (e.g. `index++`).

Comment: It's not *mutating* the index, but it's also not very hygienic to touch the index... Why this was voted "unclear what you're asking" does not make sense to me. I'm voting to re-open this question.

Comment: I can't currently answer, but my answer would be to use a reduce function instead. Simply pass the previous value in instead of any true reduction as the 'accumulator' parameter. Be careful of the edge cases of the first and last elements of the index. This would be a fully functional equivalent and would involve no index math, which I understand you want to avoid. • Update, since you still want the functionality of map, perhaps my suggestion could be tweaked so that the accumulator becomes a tuple containing the both the last value and a growing array equivalent to the intended map result

Comment: You're looking for a [`scan` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanl), which JS unfortunately doesn't provide natively.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think the OP is looking for the `scan` function. He wants a function of the type `(a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` where the mapping function takes adjacent elements as inputs. Note that such a function is not well defined for empty arrays.

Comment: @AaditMShah Oops, I actually meant the [`mapAccum` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL), which would enable a simple implementation

Comment: @AaditMShah but can it be simply defined? Ie, is there something wrong with returning `[]` for empty/singleton inputs?

Comment: @user633183 I made a mistake by using the wrong terminology. I meant to say that "such a function is **undefined** for empty arrays." Apparently, not well-defined is not the same as undefined. For example, the reciprocal of zero is undefined in mathematics but most people "define" it as the limit of x as x tends to zero, which is infinity. Similarly, the `mapAdjacent` of an empty array is undefined because there are no adjacent elements in an empty array. Hence, a good type system would prevent you from writing such code. However, you can define it to be an empty array like I did in my answer.

Comment: @user633183 It should be noted that `mapAdjacent(f, [x]) === []`. Hence, if you define `mapAdjacent(f, []) === []` too then you wouldn't be able to distinguish between the output of an empty array and a one element array. That's more reason to leave `mapAdjacent(f, [])` as undefined. You shouldn't be applying the `mapAdjacent` function to an empty array to begin with (i.e. applying the `mapAdjacent` function to an empty array should be either a compile-time type error or a runtime error). Another option would be to return a `Maybe` value.

Answer (score 1):

Not a particularly fast implementation, but destructuring assignment makes it particularly elegant -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const mapAdjacent = (f, [ a = None, b = None, ...more ] = []) =>
  a === None || b === None
    ? []
    : [ f (a, b), ...mapAdjacent (f, [ b, ...more ]) ]

const pair = (a, b) =>
  [ a, b ]

console.log(mapAdjacent(pair, [ 1, 2, 3 ]))
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]

console.log(mapAdjacent(pair, "hello"))
// [ [ h, e ], [ e, l ], [ l, l ], [ l, o ] ]

console.log(mapAdjacent(pair, [ 1 ]))
// []

console.log(mapAdjacent(pair, []))
// []
```

Or write it as a generator -

```js
const mapAdjacent = function* (f, iter = [])
{ while (iter.length > 1)
  { yield f (...iter.slice(0,2))
    iter = iter.slice(1)
  }
}

const pair = (a, b) =>
  [ a, b ]

console.log(Array.from(mapAdjacent(pair, [ 1, 2, 3 ])))
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]

console.log(Array.from(mapAdjacent(pair, "hello")))
// [ [ h, e ], [ e, l ], [ l, l ], [ l, o ] ]

console.log(Array.from(mapAdjacent(pair, [ 1 ])))
// []

console.log(Array.from(mapAdjacent(pair, [])))
// []
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce() function provides a functional what you need:

```
items.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  if(currentValue.id === previousValue.id) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: "previous value" in this context does not mean "previous element"; It is the accumulator, or as the docs put it: "the value resulting from the previous call to callbackFn". As such, this answer is not only irrelevant, but also incorrect.

Comment: Just set into the accumulator a previous value and have a nice day. My example explains the reduce() function in the concrete case. KISS))

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, I would suggest using `reduce`. Here is an example:

```js
const input = [
  {id: 1, value: "Apple Turnover"},
  {id: 1, value: "Apple Turnover"},
  {id: 2, value: "Banana Bread"},
  {id: 3, value: "Chocolate"},
  {id: 3, value: "Chocolate"},
  {id: 3, value: "Chocolate"},
  {id: 1, value: "Apple"},
  {id: 4, value: "Danish"},
];

// Desired output: Array of strings equal to values in the above array,
// but with a prefix string of "New: " or "Repeated: " depending on whether
// the id is repeated or not

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  let previousValue, descriptions, isRepeatedFromPrevious;
  
  if (accumulator) {
    previousValue = accumulator.previousValue;
    descriptions = accumulator.descriptions;
    isRepeatedFromPrevious = previousValue.id === currentValue.id;
  } else {
    descriptions = [];
    isRepeatedFromPrevious = false;
  }
  
  if (isRepeatedFromPrevious) {
    // The following line is not purely functional and performs a mutation,
    // but maybe we do not care because the mutated object did not exist
    // before this reducer ran.
    descriptions.push("Repeated: " + currentValue.value);
  } else {
    // Again, this line is mutative
    descriptions.push("New: " + currentValue.value);
  }
 
  return { previousValue: currentValue, descriptions }
};


const output = input.reduce(reducer, null).descriptions;

document.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<output id=output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want a map? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you want to map over adjacent elements of an array then you'd have to define your own function.

```js
const mapAdjacent = (mapping, array) => {
    const {length} = array, size = length - 1, result = new Array(size);
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) result[i] = mapping(array[i], array[i + 1]);
    return result;
};

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const result = mapAdjacent((x, y) => [x, y], items);

console.log(result); // [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Note that this will throw a `RangeError` if you give it an empty array as input.

```js
const mapAdjacent = (mapping, array) => {
    const {length} = array, size = length - 1, result = new Array(size);
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) result[i] = mapping(array[i], array[i + 1]);
    return result;
};

const items = [];

const result = mapAdjacent((x, y) => [x, y], items); // RangeError: Invalid array length

console.log(result);
```

I think this is good behaviour because you shouldn't be giving `mapAdjacent` an empty array to begin with.

---

Here's a purely functional implementation of `mapAdjacent` which uses `reduceRight`. As an added bonus, it works for any iterable object.

```js
const mapAdjacent = (mapping, [head, ...tail]) =>
    tail.reduceRight((recur, item) => prev =>
        [mapping(prev, item), ...recur(item)]
      , _ => [])(head);

const items = "hello";

const result = mapAdjacent((x, y) => [x, y], items);

console.log(result); // [['h', 'e'], ['e', 'l'], ['l', 'l'], ['l', 'o']]
```

Unlike the iterative version, it returns an empty array instead of throwing an error if you give it an empty array as input.

```js
const mapAdjacent = (mapping, [head, ...tail]) =>
    tail.reduceRight((recur, item) => prev =>
        [mapping(prev, item), ...recur(item)]
      , _ => [])(head);

const items = "";

const result = mapAdjacent((x, y) => [x, y], items);

console.log(result); // []
```

Note that this is an unintended side effect of array destructuring with rest elements in JavaScript. The equivalent Haskell version does raise an exception.

```hs
mapAdjacent :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapAdjacent f (x:xs) = foldr (\y g x -> f x y : g y) (const []) xs x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ mapAdjacent (,) "hello" -- [('h','e'),('e','l'),('l','l'),('l','o')]
    print $ mapAdjacent (,) "" -- Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function mapAdjacent
```

However, returning an empty array might be desirable for this function. It's equivalent to adding the `mapAdjacent f [] = []` case in Haskell.

Comment: Thanks for linking XY problem. That's practically universally relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I use an implementation of F#'s `pairWise` function:

```js
function* pairWise(seq) {
  if (!seq?.length) return;

  let a = seq[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < seq.length; i++) {
    const b = seq[i];
    yield [a, b];
    a = b;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
[...pairWise([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])] // [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
  .map(([item1, item2], index) => null);

[...pairWise('hi!')] // [['h, 'i'], ['i', '!']]
```

pairWise itself isn't implemented in a purely functional manner. It probably could but I couldn't be bothered.